# How to duplicate a PHP file using PHP

Tags: php, file

How can I duplicate a php file that I already created and place it into a different directory when a user pushes the submit button

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function as:

```
if ( copy($srcFilename,$destPath) ) {
  // file copied.
} else {
  // error occurred..call error_get_last() function for err details.      
}
```

Few things to note:

- If the destination file exists,
  `copy` will ***overwrite*** it. If you don't
  want this you can check the existence
  of the destination file using
  [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function before you
  copy.
- Both the parameters of copy must be
  ***files***. In Linux we usually do: `cp
  file dir` to copy the file `file`
  into the directory `dir` with the
  name `file`. This will not work with
  `copy`.
- Some hosting companies ***disable*** copy
  function for security reasons. In
  that case you can implement your own
  copy by reading the file using
  `file_get_contents` and
  writing to the file using
  `file_put_contents`. Since you want to copy PHP scripts (which are not very large memory wise) this will work fine.